# SQL database encryption

Tags: sqlite

Hi I am new to SQLite database and I want to encrypt and decrypt a database for research purposes. I am correct in saying the there is no built in mechanism to encrypt in SQLite database? I am looking for a simple way to encrypt the database and then decrypt it?

Comment: The sqlite developers sell [an extension that adds encryption](https://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html) for a few thousand USD.

Comment: [DB Browser for sqlite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) has an option (File -> Set Encryption). You would only ever be able to open the database in that app. But it's simple :)

Comment: i need it that it can open in any app??